# Sending to a context manager defined using contextlib.contextmanager

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, contextmanager

Suppose I have a context manager:

```
@contextmanager
def cm(x):
    y = f(x)
    z = yield y
    g(z)
```

How do I send `z` into the context manager?

I tried:

```
my_cm = cm()
with my_cm:
    my_cm.gen.send(123)
```

but I get StopIteration, which might be because `send` yields?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@contextmanager` returns a helper function that in turn returns a `GeneratorContextManager` instance, that *uses* your generator as a way to manage the context.

It is not intended to be used as anything you can send to, `next()` is called in `__enter__`. You could try and access the underlying generator with the `.gen` attribute:

```
my_cm.gen.send(123)
```

but you'd have to include an *extra* yield statement to prevent the method from exiting prematurely. Note that `__exit__` will call `next()` once more to conclude the generator.

```
@contextmanager
def cm(x):
    y = f(x)
    a = yield y   # Run for `__enter__`, returning `y`; `.send()` resumes here
    yield         # Here we pause again
    g(a)
```

works, in that it has a second `yield` to pause the generator again until the context manager is ready to call `next()` one last time.

Comment: Thanks.  I take it this is not Pythonic?  Maybe I should send `z` by setting an attribute on the yielded `y`?

Comment: Not sure if it is Pythonic; it is outside of the usecase for `@contextmanager`. I'd use a dedicated class instead (just implement `__enter__` and `__exit__`) then add any methods I'd need.

Comment: But you could indeed yield something from the `cm()` generator that can be manipulated further, then use *that* object to then pass something to `g()`. I'd prefer a dedicated class.

Comment: I think your version confuses the running order. Maybe `a = yield y`; `g(a)`; `yield "This will be returned from send()"` would be more correct: the first one yields `y`, and gets back on the send. Then `g(a)` is called and then the `send()` returns.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, but this `next()` returns the first `yield`ed value. The generator sits there until the `send()` gives its value, which causes the suspended first `yield` in the generator to produce a value and run until the next `yield`, which pongs back to `send()`.

Comment: Sorry, this was incomplete. http://codepad.org/ZkiYlyKm is the corrected version.

Comment: @glglgl: Thanks for calling me out on this; corrected the answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You're welcome. Your version now runs `g(a)` at the very end, after the complete stuff has run. An alternative could be to put `g(a)` before the last `yield`, then it gets executed directly after `send()` and before the commands after `send()` (if there are any).

Comment: Yup, also an option. The OP did not specify expectations about when `g()` should be called.